# problem connecting to unity server running on VPS

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine, server, vps

I am trying to make an online turn based game in Unity engine, so i wrote a simple server based on Jason in unity that gets username and stores some values on MongoDB in VPS(running win server 2019) and sends back requested info to client,
now it works fine when i run both server and client on VPS at the same time, but when i run client from another PC(win10), it connects to server but doesn't get requested information back from server.
i have allowed used IP and port on VPS and client pc too, firewall is set to OFF in both of them.
i would appreciate any answer that help me to figure out what is wrong, thanks to everyone:)

Server running on VPS
[image]

Client running on VPS
[image]

I run both server and client as Administrator also enabled all programs on pc through firewall!! but didn't help.
Double checked IP's and Ports (changed them from 127.0.0.1 to VPS Static IP of course!) Re_Started server couple of times but problem still persists.

Comment: The server is a listener.  When a connection is made you need to send the response back to the remote endpoint IP address.  There is a socket and you have to make sure you send the response to the same socket where there request was made.  Look at listener and find the socket.  I would use a Async Listener.  Every time a new connection is made the Accept method contains a new socket for the connection.  So you will have an array of sockets (one for each client).  You need to send any response back to the right socket.

Comment: thank you for your answer Jdweng  , but i bought another VPS and that works fine so why my current vps didn'd?   i don't know

Comment: Are two VPS in the same subnet.  You posting made it sound like the issue was two connection simultaneously.  Now that you said it working on another VPS sounds more like a route issue between two machines.  You must have a route and a return route for a connection to complete.  To test route try ping from client to server, and server to client.  I've seen cases where ping works in one direction and not another.  But in your case the connection is completing.  That is why I suspect it is two simultaneous connections is the issue.  With new VPS you are not getting two simultaneous connections.

Comment: thanks i'll try ping to see if direction is the problem